# Is there any way to order by specific column when using find_each?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am going to sort **books** by **name**.

```
Books.order(:name).find_each(batch_size: 50) do |book|
end
```

But this doesn't work.

```
[1m[36mBook Load (411.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "books".* FROM "books" ORDER BY "books"."id" ASC LIMIT $1[0m  [["LIMIT", 50]]
```

Is there any way to `order by specific column` when using `find_each`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you could add a pagination gem (you may already have one in your Gemfile, `will_paginate` or `kaminari`)

That would let you do...

```
total_batches = (Book.all.count / 50.0).ceil
(1..total_batches).each do |batch|
  Book.order(:name).paginate(page: batch, per_page: 50).each do |book|
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [`find_each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) docs:

> It's not possible to set the order. That is automatically set to
>   ascending on the primary key (“id ASC”) to make the batch ordering
>   work. This also means that this method only works when the primary key
>   is orderable (e.g. an integer or string).

Comment: How can I use unscope(:order) on Books.order(:name).find_each(batch_size: 50)?

Comment: Yes, @yu-coder is right... "Scoped order is ignored, it's forced to batch order."

Comment: Yup, sorry for that.